# Prove $\log_bf(x)$ is big-theta $\log f(x)$

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

How can I prove that $\log_bf(x)$ is big-theta of $\log f(x)$ for any constant $b > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$\log_b(y)=\frac{\log y}{\log b}.$$

**Remark:** Slightly more generally, we have the change of base formula
$$\log_b(y)=\frac{\log_a y}{\log_a b}.$$
This can be rewritten as $\log_a y=(\log_a b)(\log_b y)$, and then verified by raising $a$ to the power of each side.

Comment: Hey Andre, thanks so much for all the help! How are you so good at math and proofs? xD I want to learn your ways xD

Comment: When you have been doing it as long as I have, you may be much better than I am.

Comment: Nooo I don't know about that, you are a beast. I'm struggling in my Discrete mathematics and probability theory class and don't know how to become better at this kind of stuff, do you have any advice?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Alright thank you Andre, I appreciate it a lot!